# Removing Application Pool with special character

Tags: powershell, iis

I have accidentally created IIS application pool with name that has curly brackets and hashes.  I'm trying to remove this via PowerShell

I've tried `Remove-WebAppPool`:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Remove-WebAppPool '#{Tenant_BrandId}'
```

This keep coming back with Error:

> remove-item : Input string was not in a correct format.

I've also tried:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
cd IIS:\AppPools
Remove-Item -LiteralPath '#{Tenant_BrandId}'
```

This still comes back with:

> Remove-Item : Cannot find path '{Tenant_BrandId}' because it does not exist.

Comment: unfortunately my machine doesn't have the IIS module to test, but can you do `get-webapppool | where { $_.Name -match "Tenant_BrandID" } | remove-webapppool` or failing that, use ASCII? [char]35 [char]123 and [char]125 ?

Comment: Tried This `get-IISAppPool | Where { $_.Name -match "BrandId" } | Remove-WebAppPool` this come back with "remove-item : Input string was not in a correct format. "

Comment: Found this work `& $appcmd delete apppool '#{Tenant_BrandId}_ServiceRedirect'` where `$appCmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"`

Comment: I would be good to find out how to do this without appcmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

This does seem rather cumbersome, but I got it working using the .NET class Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL'
$iis = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::new()
($iis.ApplicationPools | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq '#{Tenant_BrandId}'}).Delete()
$iis.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below PowerShell script to remove an application pool:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" -name "." -AtElement @{name='#{Tenant_BrandId}'}
```